# Show SQL value using Node

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm using Node.js to create a Discord Bot. I want to display all the custom commands when a user types `!commands all`, the Table looks as follows

```
| | guildname | guildid | commandname | commandreply | username | userid
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| | MyServer    1002      !test         This is test   Rusty      890
```

I have got this code:

```
var info = {
  "guildname": message.guild.name,
  "guildid": message.guild.id,
  "commandname": args[0],
  "commandreply": args.join(" ").slice(args[0].length),
  "username": message.author.username,
  "userid": message.author.id
}

connection.query("SELECT * FROM commands WHERE guildid = '" + message.guild.id + "'", info, function(error, commandExists) {
  if (error) throw error;

  if (commandExists.length) {
    console.log(commandname); // commandname is not defined
  }
}
```

How do I access one of those values, for example, the commandname?

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of concatenating SQL strings and instead use placeholder values whenever possible. That is `WHERE guildid=?` and then include the appropriate values as directed by your driver. It's also probably a super bad plan to throw errors inside asynchronous code. That screws up a lot of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`results` will contain an array of objects, where each object will contain the selected fields with their values.

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM commands WHERE guildid = '" + message.guild.id + "'", info, (error, results, fields) => {

    // error will be an Error if one occurred during the query 
    // results will contain the results of the query 
    // fields will contain information about the returned results fields (if any) 

    if (error) throw error;

    if (results.length) {
        results.forEach(command => {
            console.log(command.commandname);
        });
    }
});
```

The query can be improved using [placeholders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#custom-format).

If you're using [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) or [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) here's how:

```
connection.config.queryFormat = function (query, values) {
  if (!values) return query;
  return query.replace(/\:(\w+)/g, function (txt, key) {
    if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return this.escape(values[key]);
    }
    return txt;
  }.bind(this));
};

connection.query("SELECT * FROM commands WHERE guildid = :guildId", { guildId: message.guild.id });
```

Check this question:

[How can prepared statements protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks)

**EDIT**

In mysql2 there's built in support for [named placeholders.](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Extras.md#named-placeholders)

Comment: there is built in support for this - https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Extras.md#named-placeholders

Comment: You're right for mysql2 (Never saw it, thanks!), but mysql package does not have it.